# Angular pass a variable using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to pass a variable  `user=true`  when include the html.

I already tried using `scope` in the div element

> ```
> <div class="col-md-2 side-bar" ng-include="'/modules/coreUsers/views/settings/user-settings-side-bar.html'"
>   scope="user=true">
> ```

But didn't work.

In the `user-settings-side-bar.html`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active:user}"  class=" padb10 padt10"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="#!/user/profile">Update profile</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:order}" class=" padb10 padt10" ><i class="fa fa-history"></i> <a href="#!/user/orders">Order history</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:favorite}"class=" padb10 padt10" ><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><a href="#!/user/favoritos">Favoritos</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:privacy}" class=" padb10 padt10"><i class="fa fa-book"></i><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Included HTML can access the scope so `user` should be available. If it's "just not there" try to make it an object and use dot notation, i.e. `active.user= true` and then ` ng-class="{active: active.user}" ``.

Comment: thanks! @MikkoViitala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`onload`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to accomplish this:

**Markup**

```
<div ng-include="/modules/coreUsers/views/settings/user-settings-side-bar.html'"
 onload="user=true">
```

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I though that's native function..I checked it and did +1

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to pass variables to `ng-include`, that template can access to parent controller variables.